# Pasar datos de una función a otra en el controlador - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy integrado un tpv virtual de redsys en mi APP. Resulta que en la API creamos un controlador que abre la aplicación de redsys para realizar el pago y este te devuelve a otro controlador para poder hacer lo que necesitas con los datos de la respuesta, por ejemplo guardarlo en la BD. Bien hasta ahí está correcto, pero desde el carrito (confirmar-pedido) mando unos datos, como por ejemplo el nombre de la persona que compra, y claro esta, que en la respuesta de pago ya no puedo acceder a ellos.

Este es el controlado que gestiona el pago:

```
public static function index(Request $request)
    {
        
        try{
            //dd($request);
            $key = config('redsys.key');
            $display = false;
            Redsys::setAmount($request->total);
            Redsys::setOrder(time());
            Redsys::setMerchantcode(config('redsys.merchantcode')); //Reemplazar por el código que proporciona el banco
            Redsys::setCurrency('978');
            Redsys::setTransactiontype('0');
            Redsys::setTerminal(config('redsys.terminal'));
            Redsys::setMethod('T'); //Solo pago con tarjeta, no mostramos iupay
            Redsys::setNotification(config('redsys.url_notification')); //Url de notificacion
            Redsys::setUrlOk(config('redsys.url_ok')); //Url OK
            Redsys::setUrlKo(config('redsys.url_ko')); //Url KO
            Redsys::setVersion('HMAC_SHA256_V1');
            Redsys::setTradeName('Depildiodo');
            Redsys::setTitular('Ceivan Esthetic S.L');
            Redsys::setEnviroment(config('redsys.enviroment')); //Entorno test

            $signature = Redsys::generateMerchantSignature($key);
            Redsys::setMerchantSignature($signature);
            Redsys::setAttributesSubmit('btn_submit', 'btn_id', 'Enviar', 'display:none');
            return Redsys::executeRedirection();

            
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $form;

        
    }
```

El controlador de respuesta de pago:

```
public function respuestaPago(Request $request)
    {
        
        $key = config('redsys.key');
        $parameters = Redsys::getMerchantParameters($request->input('Ds_MerchantParameters'));
        $DsResponse = $parameters["Ds_Response"];
        $DsResponse += 0;

        //dd($parameters);

        if (Redsys::check($key, $request->input()) && $DsResponse <= 99) {
            
            $cart = Session::get('cart');
            $contador = Cart::count(); 
            $consecutivos = DB::table('consecutivos')->first();
            $anio = date('Y');
            $consecutivo = $consecutivos->consecutivo;
            $idpedido = $anio."".$consecutivo;
            $consenew = $consecutivo + 1;
            $affected = DB::table('consecutivos')
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->update([ 'consecutivo' => $consenew ]);

            foreach ($cart as $key => $order) {
                //dd($order); 
                $data = json_decode($order, true);
                
                
                foreach($data as $key => $item){
                    $opt = new Order;
                    $opt->id_cliente = $request->input('idusuario');
                    $opt->cliente = $request->input('persona');
                    $opt->dni = $request->input('dni');
                    $opt->producto = $item['name'];
                    $opt->tarifa = $item['options']['tarifa'];
                    
                    $opt->cantidad = $item['qty'];
                    $opt->total = round($item['subtotal'], 2);
                    
                    $opt->ticket = $idpedido;
                    $opt->sms = $request->input('sms1');
                    $opt->metodo = $request->input('metodoPago');
                    $opt->entrega = $request->input('entrega');
                    $opt->facturacion = $request->input('facturacion');
                    
                    $opt->save();
                } 
                
            }
            //dd($item); 
            Cart::destroy();

            return redirect('mi-cuenta')->with('info', 'Pedido realizado correctamente!');


        } else {
            //lo que quieras que haga si no es positivo

        }
    }
```

Todos los datos que intento ingresar como por ejempo `$request->input('idusuario');` llegan al controlador de arriba. He pensado varias opciones pero ninguna me funciona.

1. Una vez que llega el primer controlador, hacer la inserccion del pedido en la bd y luego en la respuesta editarle el estado del pedido (pagado/rechazado) según la respuesta que venga. Pero he probado poner la insercción en la BD en el controlador de arriba sin éxito.
2. Hacer publica la variable `$request` de arriba para acceder a los datos que necesito, pero nada tampoco funciona.

Y ya no se me ocurre nada más, alguna sugerencia??

Comment: No entendí si las dos funciones están en la misma clase o en dos controladores distintos?

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ si están en la misma clase

Comment: No sé como funciona lo de Redsys, sobre todo que es lo que hace ese `return Redsys::executeRedirection();`. Se me ocurre que puedes recibir el request en una función y en la otra procesar el pago, entonces  en la que recibes el request lo primero que haces es llamar a la otra función, si sale todo bien con el pago, continúas en la primer función donde tienes el request.